# A problem about the order of element in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Assume $a \in G$, where $G$ is a group and element $a$'s order is $mn$ with $(m,n) = 1$, the problem is to prove  there exist elements $b$ and $c$ in the group where $a = bc = cb$ , $b$'s order is $m$ and $c$'s order is $n$ and $b,c$ are unique.

I have proven that the existence of b and c using $ms+nt = 1$, but still don't know how to prove the uniqueness.

Comment: Let $G$ be defined by generators $b,c,b',c'$ and relations $b^2=b'^2=c^3=c'^3=1$ and $bc=cb=b'c'=c'b'$. Does $b=b'$ hold in that group?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier that is my puzzle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a=bc$ and $b$ and $c$ commute, then$$a^m=b^mc^m=c^m$$and$$c=c^{ms+nt}=(c^m)^s=a^{ms}.$$By the same argument, $b=a^{nt}$.

Now, suppose that $m',n'\in\mathbb Z$ are such that $m's+n't$ is also $1$. Then $m'=m+kmn$ and $n'=n-kmn$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$. Therefore, $a^{ms}=a^{m's}$ and $a^{nt}=a^{n't}$. So, $b$ and $c$ are unique.

Comment: If b and c also have the form of $a^k$ then I know how to prove that , but must such situation happen?

Comment: Now that's an answer. Should be $c^m$ though in first line.

Comment: @R.Sherlock Well… yes. I proved it in my first paragraph, right?!

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I think that it also affects the second line. But the idea is there anyway.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Right. Think you for editing it. It looks fine now.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos oh thank you!

Comment: @R.Sherlock If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos OK

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $\mathbb Z_{mn}\cong \mathbb Z_m\times \mathbb Z_n$ where $(m,n)=1$. The uniqnes comes from the propery of "direct product".

Comment: But must b and c have the form of $a^k$? Will there exist other forms that b and c and be?

Comment: @R.Sherlock: if $a=bc=cb$ then $a^m=(bc)^m=b^mc^m=c^m$. Then you can see that $c\in <a>$

Comment: @R.Sherlock: I guess still not clear for you?

Comment: oh I understand what you think, thanks

Comment: @R.Sherlock: You are welcome.